# How can I refresh HTML content using node.js

Tags: node.js

I studying Node.js.

I have some problems.

```
var http = requite('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
             res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}); 
             res.end(lastPng);
});
```

this is my code. I want to reload the browser (localhost:8080).

how can i do that?

Comment: This code makes no sense.  lastPng is not defined anywhere, you're not actually listening to anything... and you can't reload a browser page from the server without serious skullduggery.

Comment: Try to use reload npm module refer [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload)

Comment: sorry...some codes are missing

Comment: but i want to refresh some different image contents automatic

Answer (score 0):

To get you started try the following code:

```
var http = require('http'); // note that you had a typo here 'requite' 
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
         // Changed the content type to text/plain for demo
         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
         // Now you are rendering 'Hello World'
         res.end('Hello World');
});
// You need to start your server listening on port 8080
server.listen(8080);
```

If you go to http://localhost:8080 you will see the text 'Hello World'